# panda dataframe indexes get messed up and duplicate rows when adding one column to another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes `df_orders` and `df_sku_list` with the same number of rows.

I want to add a new column to df_orders that is exactly like the single column in df_sku_list.

Have reset indexes on both dataframes.

```
>>> df_orders.reset_index(drop=True)
       OrderNo  PledgeID   ReferrerID FulfillmentStatus                FundingDate  PaymentMethod      ...       ShippingZip/PostalCode ShippingCountry skucount ArticleNo ArticleName  NumberOfItems
0     6895.000  24042541          nan            Placed  2018-08-06 06:23:55 -0700            nan      ...                     ="11201"   United States        5         0           0              0
1     6895.000  24042541          nan            Placed  2018-08-06 06:23:55 -0700            nan      ...                     ="11201"   United States        5         0           0              0
2     6895.000  24042541          nan            Placed  2018-08-06 06:23:55 -0700            nan      ...                     ="11201"   United States        5         0           0              0
3     6895.000  24042541          nan            Placed  2018-08-06 06:23:55 -0700            nan      ...                     ="11201"   United States        5         0           0              0
4     6895.000  24042541          nan            Placed  2018-08-06 06:23:55 -0700            nan      ...                     ="11201"   United States        5         0           0              0
5     6894.000  24040780 18497676.000            Placed  2018-08-05 22:28:46 -0700            nan      ...                     ="27517"   United States        3         0           0              0
6     6894.000  24040780 18497676.000            Placed  2018-08-05 22:28:46 -0700            nan      ...                     ="27517"   United States        3         0           0              0
7     6894.000  24040780 18497676.000            Placed  2018-08-05 22:28:46 -0700            nan      ...                     ="27517"   United States        3         0           0              0
8     6893.000  24040663          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:59:40 -0700            nan      ...                    ="880000"         Vietnam        4         0           0              0
9     6893.000  24040663          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:59:40 -0700            nan      ...                    ="880000"         Vietnam        4         0           0              0
10    6893.000  24040663          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:59:40 -0700            nan      ...                    ="880000"         Vietnam        4         0           0              0
11    6893.000  24040663          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:59:40 -0700            nan      ...                    ="880000"         Vietnam        4         0           0              0
12    6892.000  24040660          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:58:46 -0700            nan      ...                    ="388598"       Singapore        5         0           0              0
13    6892.000  24040660          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:58:46 -0700            nan      ...                    ="388598"       Singapore        5         0           0              0
14    6892.000  24040660          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:58:46 -0700            nan      ...                    ="388598"       Singapore        5         0           0              0
15    6892.000  24040660          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:58:46 -0700            nan      ...                    ="388598"       Singapore        5         0           0              0
16    6892.000  24040660          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:58:46 -0700            nan      ...                    ="388598"       Singapore        5         0           0              0
17    6891.000  24040072          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 19:26:49 -0700            nan      ...                     ="94107"   United States        3         0           0              0
```

Here's the result from resetting index on sku_list

```
>>> df_sku_list.reset_index(drop=True)
       SKU_list
0      SKU00066
1      SKU00067
2      SKU00066
3      SKU00067
4      SKU00078
5      SKU00066
6      SKU00074
7      SKU00074
8      SKU00066
9      SKU00066
10     SKU00074
11     SKU00074
12     SKU00067
13     SKU00066
14     SKU00067
15     SKU00066
16     SKU00078
17     SKU00067
18     SKU00074
19     SKU00074
20     SKU00067
21     SKU00074
22     SKU00074
23     SKU00066
24     SKU00074
25     SKU00074
26     SKU00067
27     SKU00066
28     SKU00074
29     SKU00074
...         ...
```

The I try to add the df_sku_list's only column

```
>>> df_orders['SKU_list'] = df_sku_list['SKU_list']
>>> df_orders
      OrderNo  PledgeID   ReferrerID FulfillmentStatus                FundingDate  PaymentMethod    ...    ShippingCountry skucount ArticleNo ArticleName NumberOfItems  SKU_list
0    6895.000  24042541          nan            Placed  2018-08-06 06:23:55 -0700            nan    ...      United States        5         0           0             0  SKU00066
0    6895.000  24042541          nan            Placed  2018-08-06 06:23:55 -0700            nan    ...      United States        5         0           0             0  SKU00066
0    6895.000  24042541          nan            Placed  2018-08-06 06:23:55 -0700            nan    ...      United States        5         0           0             0  SKU00066
0    6895.000  24042541          nan            Placed  2018-08-06 06:23:55 -0700            nan    ...      United States        5         0           0             0  SKU00066
0    6895.000  24042541          nan            Placed  2018-08-06 06:23:55 -0700            nan    ...      United States        5         0           0             0  SKU00066
1    6894.000  24040780 18497676.000            Placed  2018-08-05 22:28:46 -0700            nan    ...      United States        3         0           0             0  SKU00067
1    6894.000  24040780 18497676.000            Placed  2018-08-05 22:28:46 -0700            nan    ...      United States        3         0           0             0  SKU00067
1    6894.000  24040780 18497676.000            Placed  2018-08-05 22:28:46 -0700            nan    ...      United States        3         0           0             0  SKU00067
2    6893.000  24040663          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:59:40 -0700            nan    ...            Vietnam        4         0           0             0  SKU00066
2    6893.000  24040663          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:59:40 -0700            nan    ...            Vietnam        4         0           0             0  SKU00066
2    6893.000  24040663          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:59:40 -0700            nan    ...            Vietnam        4         0           0             0  SKU00066
2    6893.000  24040663          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:59:40 -0700            nan    ...            Vietnam        4         0           0             0  SKU00066
3    6892.000  24040660          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:58:46 -0700            nan    ...          Singapore        5         0           0             0  SKU00067
3    6892.000  24040660          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:58:46 -0700            nan    ...          Singapore        5         0           0             0  SKU00067
3    6892.000  24040660          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:58:46 -0700            nan    ...          Singapore        5         0           0             0  SKU00067
3    6892.000  24040660          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:58:46 -0700            nan    ...          Singapore        5         0           0             0  SKU00067
3    6892.000  24040660          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 21:58:46 -0700            nan    ...          Singapore        5         0           0             0  SKU00067
4    6891.000  24040072          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 19:26:49 -0700            nan    ...      United States        3         0           0             0  SKU00078
4    6891.000  24040072          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 19:26:49 -0700            nan    ...      United States        3         0           0             0  SKU00078
4    6891.000  24040072          nan            Placed  2018-08-05 19:26:49 -0700            nan    ...      United States        3         0           0             0  SKU00078
5    6890.000  24039921 18497676.000            Placed  2018-08-05 18:56:15 -0700            nan    ...      United States        3         0           0             0  SKU00066
5    6890.000  24039921 18497676.000            Placed  2018-08-05 18:56:15 -0700            nan    ...      United States        3         0           0             0  SKU00066
5    6890.000  24039921 18497676.000            Placed  2018-08-05 18:56:15 -0700            nan    ...      United States        3         0           0             0  SKU00066
6    6888.000  24039345 18497676.000            Placed  2018-08-05 17:07:14 -0700            nan    ...        Switzerland        3         0           0             0  SKU00074
```

As you can see, the first five rows from df_orders are for the same order number. It wasn't always this way. I used the repeat function to duplicate rows as needed. For some reason, when I try to add the new column, it seems to reset the index for df_orders to the way it was before resetting it.

To duplicate the rows, I used this code in a script. skucount was a column containing an integer. The command below made that number of duplicate rows. Not sure if this information helps, but thought I'd add it as this may be where the problems lie:

```
df_orders = df_orders.loc[np.repeat(df_orders.index.values,df_orders['skucount'])]
```

Comment: reset_index doesn't work in place, are you saving the output? df_orders = df_orders.reset_index(drop=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just use the array of values from `df_sku_list['SKU_list']`:

```
df_orders['SKU_list'] = df_sku_list['SKU_list'].values
```

And it will be blind to the indices, and add a column to `df_orders` that is exactly like the single column in `df_sku_list`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However, when I drop the skucount column from df_orders, the indices go back to that strange repeating index again. It worked for that one column addition, but something is making it revert back to the original index. It's like the reset_index never happened.

Comment: I think you either have to reassign the dataframe when you reset the index (as in @Vaishali's comment), or use `inplace=True` as an argument to `reset_index`

Comment: Yes. It was inplace=True during the drop function. Thank you. Just when I feel like I am understanding this, I hit another rabbithole. :-)